# Premature end of script headers Error in python cgi script

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I am running to a problem a vps I recently moved to. I am trying to run a python cgi script, but I am getting an apache Premature end of script headers Error.

(I chmod +x the script file)

The script is pretty simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                      
import cgi, cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-type: text/html"
print "<html><body>hello scritp</body></html>"
```

Now if I name the script as test**.py** it runs fine on server. But if I do it the correct way, calling it test**.cgi** I receive a Internal Server Error.

I run the script from the terminal

```
./test.cgi
```

I get no errors

```
 Content-type: text/html
 <html><body>hello scritp</body></html>
```

Did anyone encountered before this issue? And a solution for it? :)
Cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

change the header as:

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

There must be at least an empty line between HTTP headers and body.
So

`print "Content-type: text/html\n"` will work just fine

Reference: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_message_body)

Comment: That's not an empty line. That's a line including text starting with "Content-type". An empty line is a line with nothing between the previous newline character and the newline character coming at the end of the line. So yes, \n\n is required not just \n.